# list of lists in Haskell - How can I seperate the first element of every list without map

Tags: list, haskell, design-patterns, pattern-matching, matching

for example:
My list of lists in Haskell is:

[[1,2,3], [7,6,8], [0,3,4]]

I need all first element of ervery list in list.

How can I get the output [1,7,4] without "map"?
I need a solution with pattern-matching, not this:
list x = map head x

Comment: Hint: you can nest patterns. If you have a list of pairs, you can use `f ((a,b):xs) = ...`. For a list of lists, use a similar pattern (you can use `:` twice). Remember to catch all the possible cases.

Answer (score 2):

Look at definitions of `map` and `head` functions. And then just copy implementations, combining both functions in one. To make it easier, you can just copy `map`, replacing function, passed to `map` with `head` and then use your own `head`. You can use `case <expr> of ...` expression to not implement your own head as a separate function. After doing all this stuff, you can probably refactor your function to make it more elegant.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it! ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
firsts [] = []
firsts [(x:xs)] = [x]
firsts ((x:xs):xss) = x: firsts xss


> firsts [[1,2,3], [7,6,8], [0,3,4]]
[1,7,0]
```

Comment: Is there a way to add some empty list validation for the inner lists using patterns? I didn't manage to do so.

Comment: it should fail, since there is no first element.  If you want to ignore empty sublists, you can add provision for that `firsts [[]] = []`

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Haskell but this is what I managed to create here.

I used list comprehension and pattern matching.

```
--Type definition. Not mandatory but recommended.
firstItemOfEveryList :: [[a]] -> [a]
--First pattern. If the list is empty return a empty list.
firstItemOfEveryList [] = [] 
--Catch all pattern. Receive a list of lists (xxs). For every inner list (xs <- xxs) call the head method (head xs), but only when the inner list is not null or empty (not(null xs).
firstItemOfEveryList xxs = [head xs | xs <- xxs, not(null xs)]
```

The empty list pattern is a little bit unnecessary, as it just gives the same result that the last catch. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thats very good!!! I'm a noob in Haskell. Can you explain me the part "/= []" Is this a helpfunction? Can I write this comment in a new function?

Comment: It's just a validation. I'm checking if the current inner list is not empty, because head throw a error if the list is empty. If you want to put this validation in a separated function you can do something like this:
`firstItemOfEveryList xxs = [head xs | xs <- xxs, validateList xs] where validateList x = x /= []`, or declare another function in the global scope as well

Comment: You shouldn't need any of _those_ constraints, only `Eq a`. And if you replace `xs /= []` by `not (null xs)`, you won't need that either.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Alexey. Just fixed the answer. I'm still a little lost when dealing with Haskell Typeclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer using nested pattern matching:

```
firsts :: [[a]] -> [a]
firsts      []      = []
firsts   ([]:xss)   = error "sublist is empty"
firsts ((x:xs):xss) = x:firsts xss
```